# Lightweight multi-OS monitoring platform

Tags: mysql, replication, monitoring

I have a project where there are Windows, FreeBSD and Linux servers.
I have to monitor some services:

- MySQL replication status
- www status
- status with regexp on a webpage
- space on disk

Is there open source software that can do this and be deployed rapidly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Nagios at work and I really like it. lightweight and very flexible. All thought it's very easy to setup.

If you would like a more Ui friendly and less "sysadminisch" system I would suggest [Hyperic](http://www.hyperic.com/).

Comment: Is the opensource version of Hyperic good enough to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Nagios](http://nagios.org/) and the companion NRPE for remote monitoring. It is ideal for that number of servers. It also has lots of plugins, and you can write your own if you want.

And [here are several MySQL](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Databases/Plugins/MySQL) plugins

Answer (score 0):

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) comes to mind. I haven't personally used it much, but it should be able to do all of those. I won't vouch for code quality though, it being PHP and all...

Answer (score 0):

The Open Source version of hyperic monitors just about anything in the universe, and anything that is not monitored out of the box can be monitored by creation of a super simple plugin (a single xml file usually).

If the environment is relatively small (<20 machines) you can use the prepackaged internal db, but if it is larger then you may need to look into an external db. As it is project based I guess it is small in which case you will be fine with the internal db. The agents that run on the machines you want to monitor are very lightweight.

All documented here:

[Out of the box supported](http://www.hyperic.com/products/supported-technologies.html)

[SQL Based Plugins](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/SQL+Query+Plugin)

[Pretty Much all other plugins](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOC/Measurement+Plugin)